# Is it possible to clear a temp file in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda that will scan an uploaded file and search for specific phrases which have been listed in another s3 bucket. If a phrase is matched in the original uploaded file, it will print the line of the transcript as well as the response.

This lambda works if we upload each transcript individually, however if we upload more than 1, it stores the original output and adds it to the beginning.

I feel that this issue may be caused by the /tmp/ file not being cleared when the lambda function ends.

Is there a way to clear the /tmp/ file each time a job is done?

The output looks as follows:

```
ch_0 :  Okay.  And then,  um,  how do you guys typically allocate funding for a project like this? 
-------------------------------------------------------------
ch_1 :  Yeah,  we do have capital projects and we've allocated money 3 place,  which is and stuff,  Um,  every year. 

ch_0 :  Okay.  And then,  um,  how do you guys typically allocate funding for a project like this? 
-------------------------------------------------------------
ch_1 :  Yeah,  we do have capital projects and we've allocated money 3 place,  which is and stuff,  Um,  every year. 

ch_0 :  Okay.  And then,  um,  how do you guys typically allocate funding for a project like this? 
-------------------------------------------------------------
ch_1 :  Yeah,  we do have capital projects and we've allocated money 3 place,  which is and stuff,  Um,  every year.
```

However, it should look like this:

```
ch_0 :  Okay.  And then,  um,  how do you guys typically allocate funding for a project like this? 
        -------------------------------------------------------------
ch_1 :  Yeah,  we do have capital projects and we've allocated money 3 place,  which is and stuff,  Um,  every year.
```

My lambda code is as follows:

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucketname = str(file_obj['s3']['bucket']['name'])
        filename = str(file_obj['s3']['object']['key'])
        job_name = filename
        print("Filename: ", filename)
        fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=filename)
        file_content = fileObj["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')

        budget_file = s3.get_object(Bucket= "bantp-phrases", Key="B.txt")
        budget_content = budget_file["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')

        authority_file = s3.get_object(Bucket= "bantp-phrases", Key="A.txt")
        authority_content = authority_file["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')

        need_file = s3.get_object(Bucket= "bantp-phrases", Key="N.txt")
        need_content = need_file["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')

        timeline_file = s3.get_object(Bucket= "bantp-phrases", Key="T.txt")
        timeline_content = timeline_file["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')

        partner_file = s3.get_object(Bucket= "bantp-phrases", Key="P.txt")
        partner_content = partner_file["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')

        # Converts all to a list
        budgets = budget_content.split("\n")
        authorities = authority_content.split("\n")
        needs = need_content.split("\n")
        timelines = timeline_content.split("\n")
        partners = partner_content.split("\n")
        lines = file_content.split("\n")

        directory_name = filename

        mylist = lines

        #Budget Phrase Analysis

        for b in budgets:
            with open("/tmp/budget.txt", "a") as x:
                try:
                    output = None
                    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                        if b.strip() in line:
                            output = index
                            break
                    if output:
                        x.write("\n" + lines[output] + "\n")
                        x.write("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                        x.write("\n" + lines[output +1] + "\n")
                        print ("It worked!")
                        break
                except (ValueError):
                        x.write("Nothing found")
                        print ("It didn't work :(")
                        break
        s3.upload_file(Filename = "/tmp/budget.txt" , Bucket="bantp-analysis",  Key = ((directory_name)+'/'+"Budget_" + (filename)))

        #Authority Phrase Analysis
        for a in authorities:
            with open("/tmp/authority.txt", "a") as c:
                try:
                    output = None
                    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                        if a.strip() in line:
                            output = index

                    if output:
                        c.write("\n" + lines[output] + "\n")
                        c.write("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                        c.write("\n" + lines[output +1] + "\n")
                        print ("It worked!")

                except (ValueError):
                        c.write("Nothing found")
                        print ("It didn't work :(")
        s3.upload_file(Filename = "/tmp/authority.txt" , Bucket="bantp-analysis",  Key = ((directory_name)+'/'+"Authority_") + (filename))


        #Need Phrase Analysis
        for n in needs:
            with open("/tmp/need.txt", "a") as v:
                try:
                    output = None
                    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                        if n.strip() in line:
                            output = index
                            break
                    if output:
                        v.write("\n" + lines[output] + "\n")
                        v.write("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                        v.write("\n" + lines[output +1] + "\n")
                        print ("It worked!")
                        break
                except (ValueError):
                        v.write("Nothing found")
                        print ("It didn't work :(")
                        break
        s3.upload_file(Filename = "/tmp/need.txt" , Bucket="bantp-analysis",  Key = ((directory_name)+'/'+"Need_") + (filename))


        #Timeline Phrase Analysis
        for t in timelines:
            with open("/tmp/timeline.txt", "a") as z:
                try:
                    output = None
                    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                        if t.strip() in line:
                            output = index
                            break
                    if output:
                        z.write("\n" + lines[output] + "\n")
                        z.write("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                        z.write("\n" + lines[output +1] + "\n")
                        print ("It worked!")
                        break
                except (ValueError):
                        z.write("Nothing found")
                        print ("It didn't work :(")
                        break
        s3.upload_file(Filename = "/tmp/timeline.txt" , Bucket="bantp-analysis",  Key = ((directory_name)+'/'+"Timeline_") + (filename))


        #Partner Phrase Analysis
        for p in partners:
            with open("/tmp/partner.txt", "a") as q:
                try:
                    output = None
                    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                        if p.strip() in line:
                            output = index
                            break
                    if output:
                        q.write("\n" + lines[output] + "\n")
                        q.write("-------------------------------------------------------------")
                        q.write("\n" + lines[output +1] + "\n")
                        print ("It worked!")

                except (ValueError):
                        q.write("Nothing found")
                        print ("It didn't work :(")

        s3.upload_file(Filename = "/tmp/partner.txt" , Bucket="bantp-analysis",  Key = ((directory_name)+'/'+"Partner_") + (filename))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Can you try the following solutions and comment the results please

In all your `open` operation change the mode of opening the file from `a` to `w`.

Example

```
with open("/tmp/timeline.txt", "a") as z:
```

to

```
with open("/tmp/timeline.txt", "w") as z:
```

This change for all open operations, to override the existing metafile. Also do take care of indentation.